# Error when trying to assign value after making a property optional

Tags: typescript

I am passing the state property inside props, but I want it to be optional if the GenericType is identical to ObjectLiteral type (Record<string, any>).

And in this scenario, props.state would be optional, and it would also be a type of ObjectLiteral, thus would accept '{}' as value. But this is not what is happening, I am getting an error when trying to assign '{}' to my_props.state.

```js
type ObjectLiteral = Record<string, any>;

type FuncProps<T> = {state: T};

const test = <T extends ObjectLiteral = ObjectLiteral>(props: IfEquals<T, ObjectLiteral, "same", "diff"> extends "same" ? Optional<FuncProps<T>, "state"> : FuncProps<T>) => {
    const my_props: FuncProps<T> = {...props,
        state: props.state || {}
    };
    return my_props;
}

/*
    the optional switch is working, when passing GenericType, it requires property state,
    otherwise it would not
*/
test<{address: {status: boolean}}>({ state: {address: {status: true}}});
test<Record<string, any>>({});
test({});
```

I am getting:

> (property) state: T extends ObjectLiteral = ObjectLiteral Type 'T |
> {}' is not assignable to type 'T'.   'T | {}' is assignable to the
> constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different
> subtype of constraint 'ObjectLiteral'.
> Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'T'.
> '{}' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint
> 'ObjectLiteral'.(2322) input.tsx(16, 22): The expected type comes from
> property 'state' which is declared here on type 'FuncProps'

Am I missing something?

Comment: In `FuncProps` you define `state: T`. So you can only assign `T` here and not `{}`. If you want to assign `{}` here you need to add it: `{ state: T | {} }`

Comment: @TobiasS. this makes sense, but in this case T is ObjectLiteral and '{}' is ObjectLiteral.

Comment: hmm not really. `T` just extends `ObjectLiteral` but could be a different subtype.

Comment: got it, so my_props.state need to be T | ObjectLiteral to support {}, because T is a subtype of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast `{}` to a specific type. Use this:

```
const my_props: FuncProps<T> = {...props,
    state: props.state ?? ({} as T)
};
```